# what exactly mean 2160p, 1440p, 1080p, ... 144p?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing

I need to tag each video i receive with either 2160p, 1440p, 1080p, ... 144p. But what is the exact definition of it ?

I know the definition of wikipedia :

```
2160p=3840x2160
1440p=2560×1440
1080p=1920×1080 
720p=1280×720   
480p=640×480    
360p=480×360    
240p=426×240    
144p=256×144
```

ok, but with tag to assign to a video of for example `1200x700` ? `720p` or `480p` ?
Same for a resolution of `1920x480`, did i need to assign a resolution of `480p` or `720p` or `1080p` ?

Comment: It’s just the video heght with a p if it’s pergressive or and an i  if it’s interlaced.  (Not everything is p)

Comment: thanks but on youtube for example this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU4MATCn1XA is written as 360p but it's  640x352 so is it a 360p resolution or not ?

Comment: No, it’s 352. But they call it 360 because calling it what it really is would confuse people. So they lie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> it is the pixel count.

`1200x700` simply means: `1200 pixels` in width and `700 pixels` in height

so `1920x480` would not choose one of the other resolutions, it would stretch the video

the 360p here actually stands for the height. With this value and the screen ratio you can calculate the real resulotion.

so lets asume you use a typical 16:9 screen:

- 360p = 640x360 `(360/9*16 = 640)`
- 720p = 1280x720 `(720/9*16 = 1280)`
- 1080p = 1920x1080 `(1080/9*16 = 1920)`
- and so on..

the resolution youtube uses maybe is a bit different *(e.g. the video player could be 5 pixels smaller due to the way they programmed it)* and the developer just made it easy by writing the common value, so that everybody would understand it

Comment: thanks but on youtube for example this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU4MATCn1XA is written as 360p but it's  640x352 so is it a 360p resolution or not ?

Comment: @loki I updated my answer. hopefully this will help